# the courage of that man

Tags: possessives

```
a. He mentioned the courage of Tom.

b. He mentioned the courage of President Dubcek during the Prague Spring.
```

Do you find these sentences grammatically correct?

Do you find them natural?

I think they are both grammatical, but (b) sounds natural and (a) doesn't.

I think in (a) 'Tom's courage' would be natural.

I think (b) works although 'President Dubcek's courage' would be more natural.

The question is whether one can use the 'of possessive' instead of the 'apostrophe s possessive in these cases.

I don't know why (b) sounds natural to me and (a) sounds awful.

Answer (score 1):

The inverted form "The [noun] of [person's name]" is more often used when the name is  part of, or followed by, a phrase giving more information. We can say

> *He mentioned President Dubcek's courage.*
>
> *He mentioned the courage of Tom* would be more natural if followed by *who had rescued two people from a burning building*, for example.